# Animating only the image in UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, rotation, uibarbuttonitem, uiviewanimation

Ive seen this effect in 2 apps and I REALLY want to find how to do it.

The animation is in a UIBarButtonItem, and is only to the image. The image is a + symbol, and it rotates to a X.

If you want to see the effect you have to start a conversation with someone and next to the text input theres the + button for images and emoji's. Or heres a video of the effect in another app, after he taps the bar button you see it rotate to a X, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8JW7euuNMo.

I have found out how to do the effect but only on a UIImageView, I have to turn off all the autoresizing and the view mode has to be centered, then apply the rotation transform to it. I have tried many ways of trying to have it work in a bar item and so far the best way is adding a image view instance, then setting it up and setting the view mode centered and autoresizing off and then using that image view for a custom bar item view. But when i do this, the effect works except while its doing it, the image will go off to the side a little bit instead of staying where it already is. Ive tried getting the center before the animation and set it during the animation but that doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the answer for this is you have to make a instance of the Image view, then set it up with no resizing and view mode is centered. Then add the image view to a UIButton with custom type, and then use the button as the custom view for the bar item.

```
- (IBAction)animate {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45));
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(0));
        if ([imageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add.png"]]) {
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Close.png"];
        }
        else imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Add.png"];
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Add.png"]];
    imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
    [button addSubview:imageView];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(animate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    imageView.center = button.center;
    barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = barItem;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently had to do the same thing in Swift.  I [created a tutorial](http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/how-to-animate-a-bar-button-item-swift/) that includes starter and final projects, and goes step-by-step with some tips sprinkled in.  The code looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var rightBarButton: UIBarButtonItem! {
    didSet {
        let icon = UIImage(named: "star")
        let iconSize = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: icon!.size)
        let iconButton = UIButton(frame: iconSize)
        iconButton.setBackgroundImage(icon, forState: .Normal)
        rightBarButton.customView = iconButton
        rightBarButton.customView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
            delay: 0.5,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
            initialSpringVelocity: 10,
            options: .CurveLinear,
            animations: {
                self.rightBarButton.customView!.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            },
            completion: nil
        )    

        iconButton.addTarget(self, action: "tappedRightButton", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)        
    }
}

func tappedRightButton(){
    rightBarButton.customView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * 6/5))
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
        self.rightBarButton.customView!.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the `.AllowUserInteraction` option if you want the button to be tappable during animations

Comment: why using customView type? Does that work with any other type

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to keep the expanded tapping size that the native `UIBarButtonItem` view provides (such as `-initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:` versus `-initWithCustomView:`).

Here's a basic implementation of my code.

```
- (void)setup {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(navigationBarRightAction)];
}

- (void)navigationBarRightAction {
    UIView *itemView = [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem performSelector:@selector(view)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [itemView.subviews firstObject];

    if (self.shouldRotate) {
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_4);

    } else {
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a button as a custom view, it works in fact with less code using a UIImageView and adding a UITapGestureRecognizer.

I hope my solution below helps someone b/c I struggled with this for a long time until I got the bar button item to receive taps and get it to work with all the features I wanted. In my case, I made an "alert bell" bar button item that jingles when there are notifications, and then segues to a new tableview controller when tapped.

This was my solution (Swift 5):

```
@IBOutlet weak var notifyBell: UIBarButtonItem!

    func updateNumNotesAndAnimateBell(_ numNotes: Int) {

    guard let image = UIImage(named: "alertBellFill_\(numNotes)") else { return }
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    notifyBell.customView = imageView
    notifyBell.customView?.contentMode = .center
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(notifyBellPressed))
    notifyBell.customView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    let scaleTransformA = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
    let rotateTransformA = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0.0)
    let hybridTransformA = scaleTransformA.concatenating(rotateTransformA)
    let rotateTransformB = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -1*CGFloat.pi*20.0/180.0)
    let hybridTransformB = scaleTransformA.concatenating(rotateTransformB)

    notifyBell.customView?.transform = hybridTransformA
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3,
                   delay: 1,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1,
        initialSpringVelocity: 10,
        options: [.allowUserInteraction, .curveEaseInOut],
        animations: {
            self.notifyBell.customView?.transform = numNotes > 0 ? hybridTransformB : scaleTransformA
        },
        completion: nil
    )

}
@objc func notifyBellPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNotificationsTVC", sender: self)
}
```

Key discoveries for me were that:

-- .allowUserInteraction must be included in the animate options, otherwise the UIBarButtonItem won't be active until the animation completes.

-- You will likely have to declare YourBarButtonItem.customView?.contentMode = .center when using CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: ) or else it will distort your image when it tries to rotate.

-- The code above includes a scale animation and rotate animation that is different depending on how many notifications I have. With zero notifications, the image is an empty bell, else, it displays the number of notifications in the bell image. I probably could've done this with an updating label, but I had already gone the route of making separate PNGs for each so this worked nicely.